# How do I set up iPhone from a computer?

Tags: macos, iphone, screen

How can I control my iPhone from my computer if my bottom part of the screen is unresponsive and I can't set my phone up?

Comment: Is it jailbroken?

Comment: If you have macOS then you can get [Apple Configurator 2](https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator) from the Mac App Store. Using Apple Configurator, you may update, restore or backup the iPhone.

Comment: If the screen is broken, even if you get it set up, it won’t function properly; you won’t be able to use it.    Get the phone repaired.

Answer (score 1):

First, You should get your iPhone repaired.

Next, you should be able to set up the phone by itself.

If you would rather do it on the computer, use iTunes.